# Protocol method deprecation causes warning in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, protocols, deprecation-warning

Let's say that I have a pure Swift protocol (not marked with `@objc` statement), this protocol serves as a delegate in some other class. This protocol has two methods: old method that I'd like to deprecate and new method that I'd like to introduce as a replacement:

```swift
protocol TestProtocol: AnyObject {
    
    @available(*, deprecated, renamed: "newMethod()")
    func deprecatedMethod()
    
    func newMethod()
}

class TestClass {

    weak var delegate: TestProtocol?

    func testDelegates() {
        // Warning: 'deprecatedMethod()' is deprecated: renamed to 'newMethod()'.
        delegate?.deprecatedMethod()

        delegate?.newMethod()
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let testClass = TestClass()
        testClass.delegate = self
        testClass.testDelegates()
    }
}

extension ViewController: TestProtocol {

    func deprecatedMethod() {
        print("Deprecated method.")
    }

    func newMethod() {
        print("New method.")
    }
}
```

Since class still has to call deprecated method of the protocol it causes warning. I'd like to prevent this warning. Are there any ideas on how this can be fixed?

Comment: Do you want the protocol method to be deprecated or not? If you want it deprecated but not issue a warning, then what's the point of the deprecation? How would that be different from having a comment that says "deprecated"?

Comment: Imagine that `TestProtocol` is part of public API and external users are already using that protocol to subscribe for any changes from `TestClass`. For backward-compatibility I'd like to still call deprecated method, but without triggering warning specifically in `TestClass`. At the same time users of the API will get that warning, which will tell them that they can use new method.

Comment: Check [this](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-use-available-to-deprecate-old-apis). There is a difference between deprecated and obsolete. With deprecated you can still use it until you mark it obsolete.

Comment: Thanks, I've considered this as well, but `Protocol members can only be marked unavailable in an @objc protocol`. I cannot make this change as some of the objects I use in protocol are pure Swift objects.